# django form and title property

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

i need to render my forms with the property "title" for jquery validation, how ill render my forms in this way?

```
<input name="name" id="name" title="Please fill Your name!" value="" type="text" />
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is to set this attribute manually and static like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
myfield = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'title':"MYMEGATITLE","id":"MY_ID",'size':'60','maxlength':'70'} ))
```

Comment: Is it possibble to do this at django model side instead form.