# Django forms can I change the default "Username" field in Django forms to "Job Title"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a form for a service providers booking app as part of a project. I'm just wondering can I change the default "Username" field in Django forms to "Job Title".
Here is my current "*Forms.py* file.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 
                  'email', 
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password1', 
                  'password2'
            )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: What do you mean "change to job title"? If you're using the default `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model, then `username` is a mandatory field, and must be unique. You can **add** other fields to your form (e.g. a `job_title` field) like any other form, but you'll need a model to save it to.

Comment: If you need to change the `User` model, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884382/django-form-and-title-property
May be this?